# Error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Src.main(Src.java:6)

Tags: java, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

i am using this program and getting the above error!

```
public class Src {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int b=Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int c=a+b;
        System.out.println(""+c);
    }
}
```

Comment: args is probably empty. check this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Provide more detail,how are you executing the code and all...

Comment: @shekharsuman i m running it on eclipse...

Comment: @AbhishekKumarRao-You obviously need to set arguments for main method in eclipse! There is a separate process of that in eclipse. Search on google.com!

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass some arguments at the command line, when you call the program:

```
java Src arg0 arg1
```

`args` is a `String[]` that gets filled with the command-line values passed when invoking the program, by default it's empty, hence an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown because there's nothing there at index `0`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to read the first element in the args[] array and this element doesn't exist.

The args[] array contains arguments passed during the start of the program in the command line, maybe you're not passing argument.

You can find an example of ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5554781/2649618

This is the official documentation page on Oracle website (is for Java 7): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html